# No Line Control in Silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I want to draw a line (neither vertical nor horizontal) that should be able to react to a click and drag on the line but I can't even see a line control in Silverlight: there is only Rectangle & Ellipse.

So how would I do the most easily ?

Answer (score 1):

There is Line shape in silverlight/Wpf see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.line%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), which version of silverlight do you use? It seems Line control available from 3 rd version

Comment: I'm using S4. I tried line but none appears http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800252/why-no-line-appears-on-canvas-in-silverlight