# Silverlight is completely buggy with canvas

Tags: silverlight

It's incredible that such sample code doesn't even work.

I have put this inside grid but I can't see any line (code taken from MSDN in fact):

```
    <Canvas Height="103" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,166,0,0" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180">
        <Line
X1="0" Y1="10"
X2="5" Y2="10"
Stroke="Black"
StrokeThickness="4" />
    </Canvas>
```

This is incredible that such simple thing like that would be so buggy so did I miss something see picture below ? (Everything else in silverlight works fine for me):

[image]

Update: the bug is confirmed. This is quite incredible that MS hasn't fixed this !

Comment: Your code works fine for me, I see a small black square.  I suggest you make sure your machine is up-to-date with patches and service packs.

Comment: Others confirmed it doesn't work only OUTSIDE CANVAS !

Comment: I think you need to clarify that statement.  The code you've shown above works locally and I can't replicate what you're seeing.  Typically that points to environmental factors.

Comment: I would note that inside Blend this does appear without issue, but in my Visual Studio it does in fact not work as intended.  I think this is less a Silverlight bug and more a VS defect. When I run the project in VS it does appear fine however.

Answer (score 1):

It does appear. Your line is a very small dot with 5pixel width. Try changing the coordinates to draw a longer line.

Comment: OK I make longer still nothing see picture above (I'm on silverlight 4)

Comment: its still only 5px wide, make X2="85"

Comment: @Mark said it correctly. Its still 5px. I think you would need to give width and height to the line control. Try giving a Width and height of 200 to the line control and X1=0, Y1 = 0 and X2 =50, Y2=50 coordinates

Comment: X2=85 doesn't change anything

Comment: @user310291 can you pls try what I said in the last comment?

Comment: I tried it doesn't work. Originally I took the example from MSDN so why wouldn't work that's what I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Others have confirmed with latest version of Silverlight this doesn't work except OUTSIDE OF CANVAS ! So indeed this is a huge bug.

Comment: Shows up at runtime and in Blend without issue, but in the VS designer it does not work as intended.

Comment: This is quite incredible that MS hasn't fixed this !

Answer (score 0):

I've faced exactly with that and here is my solution:

```
<Canvas Height="103" Width="180" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,166,0,0" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <Line Height="103" Width="180" X1="0" Y1="10" X2="5" Y2="10" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4" />
</Canvas>
```

Thus, you must set to same size with Line and Canvas. Actually, Line placing to where you put but it isn't showing cause hasn't size.